# Calling path helper functions inside an Unit Test setUp method throws errors

Tags: laravel, phpunit, lumen

When using Laravel/Lumen: I can apparently reference helper methods like `storage_path()`, `base_path()` etc in various PHPUnit test methods, but when I try to reference them in the `setUp()` method for my test, I receive the following error:

`Error : Call to undefined method Illuminate\Container\Container::basePath()`

How does one get these helper methods to work? Is it failing because the `setUp()` method is protected, while the other Unit test methods are public?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are calling `parent::setUp()` within your setUp method